# How to convert ILArray into double[,] array?

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

How convert ILArray into double[,] array

I have `ILArray<double> A` want to use `A.ToArray()`, but don't know how to use it

I need to get a `double[,] System.Array`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no natural support for converting an `ILArray<double>` into an multi dimensional `System.Array double[,]` in ILNumerics currently. So let's write it!

```
private static System.Array ToSystemMatrix<T>(ILInArray<T> A) {
    using (ILScope.Enter(A)) {
        // some error checking (to be improved...)
        if (object.Equals(A, null)) throw new ArgumentException("A may not be null");
        if (!A.IsMatrix) throw new ArgumentException("Matrix expected");

        // create return array
        System.Array ret = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), A.S.ToIntArray().Reverse().ToArray());
        // fetch underlying system array
        T[] workArr = A.GetArrayForRead();
        // copy memory block 
        Buffer.BlockCopy(workArr, 0, ret, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) * A.S.NumberOfElements);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

This function should work on arbitrary `ILArray<T>` of arbitrary element type and arbitrary sizes / dimensions. (However, as always, you should do extensive testing before going productive!) It creates a new System.Array of the desired size and type and copies all elements in their natural (storage layout) order. The System.Array returned can get cast to the true multidimensional array afterwards.

We use `Buffer.BlockCopy` in order to copy the elements. Keep in mind, System.Array stores its elements in row major order. ILNumerics (just like FORTRAN, Matlab and others) prefers column major order! So, since we just copy the elements quickly and do no efforts to reorder them in memory, the outcoming array will appear as having the dimensions flipped in comparison to the input array:

```
ILArray<double> C = ILMath.counter(4, 3);
var exp = ToSystemMatrix<double>(C);
```

`exp` will be of size [3 x 4]. For matrices, this can easily be circumvented by transposing the input array:

```
var exp = ToSystemMatrix<double>(C.T);
```

@Edit: bugfix: used Marshal.Sizeof(T) instead of sizeof(double) 
@Edit: bugfix: now fixed the fix: used Marshal.Sizeof(typeof(T))

Comment: Haymo I cannot make this function work. There still seems to be sth wrong in the Buffe.BlockCopy line. Marshal.SizeOf(T) gives a build error, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) does not give a build error but doesnt work

Comment: Right. I've edited the code. It reads `Marshal.Sizeof(typeof(T))`. Please clarify what does not work? Consider opening a new thread.

Comment: I have opened a new thread <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038344/how-to-convert-ilarrayobject-into-ilarraydouble>