# How to convert ILArray<object> into ILArray<double>?

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I m using ILNumerics to read and write from/to matfiles. I get some data from a database as object[,] because it contains numbers and headings (strings).

The data structure of `object[,] loaddata` is a mixture of `System.String` and `System.Double`, first two columns and first row contains strings rest doubles. I want to write the doubles into the matfile. Dimensions are roughly `loaddata[9000,500]`.

This is my very cumbersome detour via system arrays that doesnt even work:

```
ILArray<object> loaddata = DBQuery(....);
//this next line has error
var tempoobj = ToSystemMatrix<object>(loaddata["2:end", "1:end"]);
double[,] tempdouble = new double[500, 8784];
Array.Copy(tempoobj, tempdouble, tempoobj.Length);
ILArray<double> B = tempdouble;
using (ILMatFile matW = new ILMatFile())
{
      B.Name = "power";
      matW.AddArray(B);
      matW.Write(@"C:\Temp\Test.mat");
}
```

with the ToSystemMatrix function from here [How to convert ILArray into double[,] array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608356/how-to-convert-ilarray-into-double-array) - which I couldnt make work.

any ideas how to simplify this? and also how to make that function work (as it is usefull anyways).

**UPDATE**

I made this work but it feels like going at it with a sledgehammer.... But here it comes:

```
       object[,] loaddata = DBQuery(...);

        for (int i = 0; i < loaddata.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            loaddata[i, 0] = Convert.ToDouble(0);
            loaddata[i, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < loaddata.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            loaddata[0, i] = Convert.ToDouble(0);
        }

        double[,] tempdouble = new double[loaddata.GetLength(0), loaddata.GetLength(1)];
        Array.Copy(loaddata, tempdouble, loaddata.Length);
        ILArray<double> B = tempdouble;


        using (ILMatFile matW = new ILMatFile())
        {
            B.Name = "power";
            matW.AddArray(B["1:end","2:end"].T);
            matW.Write(@"C:\Temp\Test.mat");
        }
```

I also tried to use ILCell instead but `ILCell loaddata = DBQuery(...)` and `cell(loaddata)` threw errors.

Any ideas how to make this more neat?

Comment: Could you give an example of how your `ILArray<object>` data is structured?

Comment: please see second paragraph in question

Comment: I have limited understanding of how ILNumerics work, what type of object is in your array? I.e. could you show the output of `loaddata.First().GetType()`?

Comment: @decPL: sorry maybe I dont get it but I did run what you said and also loaddata.Last().GetType() and as said in second paragraph the underlying types are System.String and System.Double. Or what do you mean? Sorry I m still a learner and any help is appreciated!

Comment: no worries, we're all learning every day (I'm learning about ILNumerics now it seems ;) ). Basically I need to know - how would you translate a single entry in your `ILArray<object>` to a double. If you know how to do this, doing it for the whole set seems quite trivial (and yes, I'm willing to share :P ).

Comment: I would appreciate if you comment and tell me why you voted the question down so that I can learn and improve. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61916/discussion-between-nik-and-decpl).

Comment: Does ILArray implement IEnumerable? I am asking because using LINQ might make your life easy there.

Comment: as far as I know it does

Comment: Yes it does. But it obviously does not know the concept of multidimensionality. The enumerator rather goes straight along all elements in sequential (column major) order.

Comment: Consider using `ILCell` rather than `ILArray<object>` in order to store column headers and data in the same structure. See: [Cells](http://ilnumerics.net/Cells.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider rethinking your design. In order to return multiple information from `DBQuery(....)` you could either utilize `ILCell` or some other data structure which is able to store typed information about your headers and elements (let's say DataTable). Just object[,] seems too general.

Since I don't have specific information about your setup, I'll give one example for `ILCell`:

```
using ILNumerics;
using System;

namespace Cell_DBQuery_Example {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            using (ILScope.Enter()) {
                ILCell data = Helper.DBQuery(); 
                // data is: 
                //Cell [2,2]
                //[0]: <String>           header 1  <Double> [100,200]           
                //[1]: <String>           header 2  <Single> [2,3000]  

                // store into mat file
                ILMatFile mat = new ILMatFile();
                var key1 = (string)data.GetArray<string>(0, 0); 
                mat.AddArray(data.GetArray<double>(0, 1), key1);  // stores rand(100,200) as key: "header1"
                // proceed with other columns...

                // write mat file
                mat.Write("filename"); 
            }
        }

        class Helper : ILMath {

            public static ILRetCell DBQuery() {
                using (ILScope.Enter()) {
                    // prepare return cell
                    ILCell ret = cell(size(2, 2)); 
                    // todo: fetch data from db and replace below example data
                    ret[0, 0] = "header_1";
                    ret[1, 0] = "header_2";
                    ret[0, 1] = rand(100, 200);
                    ret[1, 1] = ones<float>(2, 3000);
                    return ret; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This creates and returns a cell in the `Helper` class. The cell contains the header and numeric data in seperate cell elements. It is than be used to retrieve the information from the cell and stores them into a mat file.

Some references: 
http://ilnumerics.net/Cells.html

http://ilnumerics.net/GeneralRules.html  - general rules for ILNumerics functions

http://ilnumerics.net/hdf5-interface.html - more options of writing compatible formats: HDF5

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
 var tempoobj = ToSystemMatrix<object>(loaddata["2:end", "1:end"]);
```

to

```
 var tempoobj = ToSystemMatrix<double>(loaddata["2:end", "1:end"]);
```

This assumes that you've selected only the part of loaddata where all the data are doubles.

Comment: Your correction of using double for the generic type (rather than object) is correct. But ToSystemMatrix<T> from the link given uses `Buffer.BlockCopy`. I would expect the elements in the `ILArray<object>` to be *boxed double* elements. A simple byte copy will not unbox them?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesnt work, because the function expects double and i dont unbox anywhere. error: The best overloaded method match for 'ReadMatFileIL.Program.ToSystemMatrix<double>(ILNumerics.ILInArray<double>)' has some invalid arguments